# Checkpointing (persistent caching) library for Spark DataFrame - use or develop - deterministic ID for DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When interactively exploring a dataset for a specific purpose in spark (e.g. using the spark-shell or a notebook), you often come to a point where you want to save the result on disk to

- simplify your execution plan
- persistently cache (or `checkpoint` in the RDD API) to use in another spark context (e.g. you go home and don't want to keep your spark-shell alive).

The point is to be able to do it relatively seamlessly in your code (minimal bloating), a bit like the `checkpoint` system on RDD's, but more persistent.

I have a few requirements for a library doing that:

1. I need to be able to `clear` my cache within a project, partially would be better
2. I need a function of the type `readOrCreate` which would either compute the DataFrame and checkpoint it, or read the checkpoint file.
3. I need those functionalities to persist when the spark context is shut down

As I see it, there is a single tricky point: I need a deterministic ID for my dataframes. I think I could use one of the plan and hash it, but it's so shallow that collisions will make it very annoying to use. Then all the cache clearing, updating etc. is only about coding the logic.

Here is my question:

- is there a library out there which already implement a persistent caching system?
- If not, has anybody a suggestion on what is the best element of a dataframe to hash in order to build a deterministic ID usable in this context?

edit: Spark version: 1.6.2 (solution in spark 2 welcome though)
edit2: any pointer (e.g. repo or issue) welcome too

PS: I can of course implement this using user provided DataFrame ID (i.e. name), but I would like to avoid that.